# Rewriting a vector equation

Tags: linear-algebra

Starting with equation (1):

$\Delta\dot{x}_i = \frac{\partial }{\partial \bar{\boldsymbol{x}}_i} \left.\left [ \boldsymbol{\varphi}_{f_i} (\bar{\boldsymbol{x}}_i)^T \boldsymbol{\theta}_{f_i}+ \boldsymbol{\varphi}_{g_i} (\bar{\boldsymbol{x}}_i)^T \boldsymbol{\theta}_{g_i} x_{i+1} \right ] \right|_{\substack{\bar{\boldsymbol{x}}_i=\bar{\boldsymbol{x}}_{i,0} \\ x_{i+1}= x_{i+1,0}}}\Delta \bar{\boldsymbol{x}}_i + \boldsymbol{\varphi}_{g_i} (\bar{\boldsymbol{x}}_{i,0})^T \boldsymbol{\theta}_{g_i} \Delta x_{i+1}, \quad i=1,\ldots,N$

where $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$, $x_{N+1} \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\bar{\boldsymbol{x_i}} = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_i), \quad i=1,\ldots,N$

and $\boldsymbol{\theta}_{f_i}, \boldsymbol{\theta}_{g_i}$ are vectors with *constant* elements.

Now I want to rewrite this in a form similar to:

$\Delta \dot{x}_i = \begin{bmatrix}
\ldots & \ldots
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\boldsymbol{\theta}_{f_i}\\ 
\boldsymbol{\theta}_{g_i}
\end{bmatrix}$

Rewriting equation (1):
$\Delta\dot{x}_i = \frac{\partial }{\partial \bar{\boldsymbol{x}}_i} \left.\left [ \boldsymbol{\varphi}_{f_i} (\bar{\boldsymbol{x}}_i)^T \boldsymbol{\theta}_{f_i} \right ] \right|_{\substack{\bar{\boldsymbol{x}}_i=\bar{\boldsymbol{x}}_{i,0} \\ x_{i+1}= x_{i+1,0}}}\Delta \bar{\boldsymbol{x}}_i + \frac{\partial }{\partial \bar{\boldsymbol{x}}_i} \left.\left [  \boldsymbol{\varphi}_{g_i} (\bar{\boldsymbol{x}}_i)^T \boldsymbol{\theta}_{g_i} x_{i+1} \right ] \right|_{\substack{\bar{\boldsymbol{x}}_i=\bar{\boldsymbol{x}}_{i,0} \\ x_{i+1}= x_{i+1,0}}}\Delta \bar{\boldsymbol{x}}_i + \boldsymbol{\varphi}_{g_i} (\bar{\boldsymbol{x}}_{i,0})^T \boldsymbol{\theta}_{g_i} \Delta x_{i+1}$

Next step:
$\Delta\dot{x}_i = \frac{\partial }{\partial \bar{\boldsymbol{x}}_i} \left.\left [ \boldsymbol{\varphi}_{f_i} (\bar{\boldsymbol{x}}_i)^T  \right ] \right|_{\substack{\bar{\boldsymbol{x}}_i=\bar{\boldsymbol{x}}_{i,0} \\ x_{i+1}= x_{i+1,0}}}\boldsymbol{\theta}_{f_i}\Delta \bar{\boldsymbol{x}}_i + \frac{\partial }{\partial \bar{\boldsymbol{x}}_i} \left.\left [  \boldsymbol{\varphi}_{g_i} (\bar{\boldsymbol{x}}_i)^T  \right ] \right|_{\substack{\bar{\boldsymbol{x}}_i=\bar{\boldsymbol{x}}_{i,0} \\ x_{i+1}= x_{i+1,0}}}\boldsymbol{\theta}_{g_i} x_{i+1}\Delta \bar{\boldsymbol{x}}_i + \boldsymbol{\varphi}_{g_i} (\bar{\boldsymbol{x}}_{i,0})^T \Delta x_{i+1}\boldsymbol{\theta}_{g_i} $

Now I don't know how to continue.